# where to put drawrect method?

Tags: iphone, ios5, drawrect

I am refering a tutorial from [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5).all thins work perfectly , but in the last where i am customizing my text field,the tutorial says "Replace the call to super with the following code"

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *textFieldBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_field_teal.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0)];
    [textFieldBackground drawInRect:[self bounds]];
}
```

but it didn't said where to put it, i have tried to put it in appdelegate and also in viewcontroller  but it display error "no visible @interface for 'detailviewcontoller' declare the selector bounds".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal thing for iOS programmers to do here is to subclass "`UITextView`", and that's what the tutorial did.  If you look in the project included with Ray's tutorial, you'll see a "Custom Views" group and inside there you'll see a "`CustomTextField`" class.

[image: Custom Text Field is here]

In there you'll find the "`drawRect`" method to update.